# Thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation

Tags: haskell, concurrency, network-programming

I have been attempting to debug a problem when using multiple MVars, however to no luck.

My code uses two MVars: one to store the servers current state, and another to pass network events to and from the client threads. However after connecting and disconnecting several times, the server stops sending data upon new clients connecting (presumably because the network events MVar is emptied for whatever reason) and eventually trips up with the error:  `*** Exception: thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation`

I have concluded the following in trying to debug this issue over the last few days:

1. The functions used to modify the MVar(s) wont throw exceptions
2. The problem does not occur until a client either connects, or connects then disconnects
3. The issue seems to occur randomly (sometimes several clients can connect then disconnect, other times it happens right away)

I have isolated the problem to three files:

1. https://github.com/Mattiemus/IMC-Server/blob/master/IMC.hs (the exception gets thrown in `sense`)
2. https://github.com/Mattiemus/IMC-Server/blob/master/IMC/Networking/Server.hs (Modifined within `application` `handleClient`, and `cleanupClient`)
3. https://github.com/Mattiemus/IMC-Server/blob/master/IMC/Utilities/Concurrency.hs (functions which push and pop to a list stored in an MVar)

I am totally out of ideas, as I  only use modifyMVar and withMVar (so surely it should never be totally left empty) - my only assumption is that maybe an Exception is being thrown while modifying the MVar, however I think this is highly unlikely.

Any help is appreciated, this problem has been bugging me for some time now.

Comment: I don't think most people will want to search through so much code to find this bug. Perhaps writing some tests will help you find it.

Comment: I have modified the question to further pin down the problem to 4 main functions. What sort of tests would I need to write to isolate this problem, the problem seems to eventually occur regardless of weather i remove all modifiers over the either the server or events MVar, leading me to believe I am somehow using them incorrectly.

There are multiple producers over the events MVar (one thread for each client) however only a single consumer - maybe this is the issue?

Comment: In `sense` you are using an `MVar` very much like a channel.  Why not use a `Chan` instead?

Comment: `modifyMVar` and `withMVar` are safe.  I do not see `swapMVar` used, which is unsafe, is it used elsewhere?

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz ```swapMVar``` was removed in favor of using modifyMVar_ due to this problem, however the core issue still persists.
I dont use ```Chan``` because I dont want to block while the channel is empty, I want to use it as if there is simply an empty list of events. See ```popAllMVar``` in Concurrency.hs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three days later and its solved: Was actually unrelated to either the networking or concurrency code, and infact caused by my incorrect re-implementation of Yampas `dpSwitch` in Netwire. Corrected code posted below for anyone wishing to implement this function:

```
dpSwitch :: (Monoid e, Applicative m, Monad m, T.Traversable col) => (forall wire. a -> col wire -> col (b, wire))
     -> col (Wire s e m b c)
     -> Wire s e m (a, col c) (Event d)
     -> (col (Wire s e m b c) -> d -> Wire s e m a (col c))
     -> Wire s e m a (col c)
dpSwitch route wireCol switchEvtGen continuation = WGen $ gen wireCol switchEvtGen
where
    gen wires switchEvtGenWire _ (Left x) = return (Left mempty, WGen $ gen wires switchEvtGenWire)
    gen wires switchEvtGenWire ws (Right x) = do            
        let routings = route x wires
        wireSteps <- T.sequenceA (fmap (\(wireInput, wire) -> stepWire wire ws (Right wireInput)) routings)
        let wireOutputs = T.sequenceA (fmap fst wireSteps)
            steppedWires = fmap snd wireSteps
        case wireOutputs of
            Left wireInhibitedOutput -> return (Left wireInhibitedOutput, WGen $ gen steppedWires switchEvtGenWire)
            Right wireResultOutput -> do
                (event, steppedSwitchEvtGenWire) <- stepWire switchEvtGenWire ws (Right (x, wireResultOutput))
                case event of
                    Left eventInhibited -> return (Left eventInhibited, WGen $ gen steppedWires steppedSwitchEvtGenWire)
                    Right NoEvent -> return (wireOutputs, WGen $ gen steppedWires steppedSwitchEvtGenWire)
                    Right (Event e) -> return (wireOutputs, continuation steppedWires e)
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who might stumble on this, some additional information `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation` is not really that smart.  It happens when every thread that contains a reference to the MVar is trying to read (or write) to that location, has died, or is waiting on another primitive that is blocked forever. eg thread 1 is trying to read MVar `a` and waiting on thread 2 which is either dead, also trying to read MVar `a`, or trying to read MVar `b` which can only be written to in thread 1.

The following code happily hangs forever:

```
do
  a <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO (readMVar a >>= print)
  putMVar a $ last $ repeat 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the problem -- it is in Server.hs. You have operations that do network IO inside a `withMVar` call. Now imagine that IO blocks effectively forever. You neither get an exception that forces the var to be replaced, nor does the operation complete normally and replace the var, and hence you get stuck.

In general, you should not do any significant operations in a `withMVar` call, even though you *can*. And if you do any such operations, you need to be double-sure that you effectively guard them with timeouts, etc. such that you are sure they always complete one way or another.

Comment: The "blocks...forever" can only trigger this exception if GHC runtime can prove it is blocked forever.  Can the network ops lead to this?

Comment: @sclv If you are pointing at the broadcast/sendTo/sendToExcept functions, then moving the network operations outside of the withMVar does not rectify the problem: the deadlock persists.